# python postdata list only gives last value of multiplecheckbox

Tags: python, post, checkbox

I made a form that has multiple checkboxes (grouped), when this data is posted it looks something like:

```
<QueryDict: {u'action': [u'delete'], u'mails': [u'1', u'2']}>
```

but now when i try to acces the data in "mails" i only get the last result:
(where postdata is my Querydict)

```
def mail_action(postdata, character):
    if postdata['action'] == "delete":
        for mail in postdata['mails']:
            print mail
```

wo with this it only prints "2"

what do i need to do to get the whole list of "mails" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for Django's [`QueryDict.__getitem__(key)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__getitem__), it says that "If the key has more than one value, `__getitem__()` returns the last value." So the behaviour you are seeing is intended.

To get all the values, try using [`QueryDict.getlist(key, default)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) which "Returns the data with the requested key, as a Python list. Returns an empty list if the key doesn’t exist and no default value was provided. It’s guaranteed to return a list of some sort unless the default value was no list."

So, your code can be:

```
def mail_action(postdata, character):
    if postdata['action'] == "delete":
        for mail in postdata.getlist('mails'):
            print mail
```